# Run to a point in a triangle in shortest time

Tags: geometry, physics

This is a generalization of a puzzle that dealt with an equilateral triangle.

Assume three runners with the following speeds - 4.5, 6.2, and 8.7 meters/sec. They are at the corners of a triangle with sides lengths of 75, 49, and 63 meters.

They need to decide how to select the corner for each runner and a point in the triangle to which they run simultaneously and reach it at the same and shortest time.

Only compass and unmarked ruler could be used to derive a solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an answer from the previous question solves this perfectly fine using apollonian circles.

Comment: It could be - the challenge is to do it with high school basic math.

Comment: Related and probably duplicate: [Shortest time to meet](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84624)

Comment: @Moti This seems like it's just a math problem. Is there some specific solution you have in mind that has [elements of a *puzzle*, not just a math problem](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784)? If not, this is going to be off-topic.

Comment: @Moti We're running into the same problem here - you can't just impose a "use basic geometry" condition because a) It was not stated in the question explicitly, and b) "basic geometry" is completely subjective.

Comment: I am not imposing - you could always use someone else work and say this problem is solved. Using your own work in a specific way with basic geometric tools makes this a puzzle. If it comes to math competition I am not sure you will call this a puzzle. @Rubio the request for basic geometry forces here a different approach than this used in the other puzzle - it requires basic knowledge in geometry and multistep process which allow anyone to attempt solution … I qualify this as a puzzle.

Comment: If there is only interest in series, words and ciphers "inventions" it is also OK but than this site is not a puzzle site and I will not make an effort to generate interesting challenges.

Comment: Further to the above - in many puzzles you are required to have understanding of geometry to solve it. In many puzzles you are limited in what you may utilize to demonstrate a solution. In puzzles you seek some unique features and combination of them that leads to a solution. In this specific one there are at least two observations that lead to a simple (relative) solution based on basic knowledge of geometry - angels on circles (inscribed and center) and similarity of triangles.